# There is soil in Archean?

Tags: geology, atmosphere, stratigraphy, precambrian, research

Following a mobilista approach over geological time, and considering the Earth's internal heat as responsible for tectonic regime, which was involved in the "Permobile type" during the early times of the Archean, what would be the pedogenesis in this context?

Comment: I'm sorry, could you clarify what is a "mobilista approach" and a "permobile type"? I'm afraid I'm not familiar with those terms.

Answer (score 3):

I don't totally understand what you are asking but yes there was soil in the Archean. In some locations around the world, these soils were buried and preserved as paleosols. The Archean paleosols are very important in studying the origin of the atmosphere because the oxidation state of the minerals is an indicator of the presence or absence oxygen and other gases in the atmosphere ([Mukhopadhyay et al., 2014](http://geology.gsapubs.org/content/early/2014/08/28/G36091.1.abstract))